# Can I generate notifications for specific user from mvc5 backend?

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, notifications, asp.net-web-api2

Can I a generate notifications to specific mobile user but with mvc5 backend not with webapi backend... thats because I have two projects one for mobile which is api and other for manage... and I want to send the notification from the manage project to mobile user.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , I can ...

By make a unique tag for each user this tag an email for example.... then when send target notification for this user use his email as tag.